# In JavaScript how would you count number of times a page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, web

Suppose you have a webpage that keeps refreshing, [like so](http://www.adelazzam.com/as.html) - how can you display a text-counter that counts to 10 ?

Comment: oK So this is a gift bounty. Please , you don't need to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple javascript would work.

use the function **setinterval()** to run some code (you can chose the time interval in miliseconds).

An example of this is here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Combine this with the **getElementById** function

```
document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML = a_variable;
```

and a div like so

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

(or instead of the div update a text input box like on the w3 example)
I've refrained from writing the code for you, but writing it should be good practice and more valuable for you.

P.S. Iam & Dave answered the question which was posed in your title - the title is slightly inaccurate. Better would be "In JavaScript how would you change the inner html of the body of a webpage at regular intervals"

Comment: btw, if you look at the source of the page you linked to it uses a function similar to setInterval(). With regards to cookies, which the other 2 answers mention... you can use them to save the result if the user happens to leave your page and come back later (and you want to continue where they left off)

Answer (score 3):

Keep the value in a cookie, or use HTML5 local DB stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookies because they are pressistant and you will be able to use the as much as you need , [here is the link on how to use them](https://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php).

I would suggest you if you are using any server side language you would be able to use Session or Cache object to preserve the values, in the end you will be able to use HTML5 Local DB.